# Where to define the root directive in nginx.conf

Tags: nginx, virtualhost

I have a question concerning the setup of nginx on a server handling different virtual hosts. I am now a bit confused where the `root` directive should be. I have seen the following two possibilities.

**Variant A**

```
server {
listen          80;
server_name     www.site.com;
access_log      /var/log/nginx/www.site.com.access.log main;
root            /var/www/$server_name/htdocs;

location / {
   index index.html;
   }
}
```

or the other one

**Variant B**

```
server {
listen          80;
server_name     www.site.com;
access_log      /var/log/nginx/www.site.com.access.log main;

location / {
   root         /var/www/$server_name/htdocs;
   index        index.html;
   }
}
```

I am a bit confused if the two variants are equal. For the different vhosts I planned to have individual `.conf` files with different `server_name` and `root` directives in `/etc/nginx/sites-available`. To activate a vhost I would have a symbolic link to the conf file in `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled`. Or would you store the configuration file in `/var/www/$server_name` to have it "close" to the www data?

So to sum up, I have two questions:
1. Which of the two variants of the `nginx.conf` file is better for the multiple vhost setup and why?
2. Where would you store the configuration files for each vhost?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Variant A is the proper way to do it. Nginx will only ever use one location block so if you define root in a location it will only be available in that location. This almost always leads to duplication of either root directives of file paths, neither of which is good.

If you define it in the server block it is always inherited by the location blocks so it will always be available in the $document_root variable, thus avoiding the duplication of file paths.

Comment: Thank you so much for this!  It make perfect sense, of course, but runs counter to all of the bad examples on the net. Most egregiously, the official "Beginner's Guide" at http://nginx.org/en/docs/beginners_guide.html is not doing anybody any favors by having EVERY SINGLE example show root directives in location blocks!

Comment: I get `the $document_root variable cannot be used in the "alias" directive` when trying to use that variable in a `location ... { alias ... }`, so I still have to use an absolute path.